# app crashes when calling removeViewAt on a grid of buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I wrote the following application where a 3 by 4 grid of buttons displayed and user can change the grid dimensions by clicking menu items. The problem is that something strange happens with the "deleteSomething" function. Below is the complete code:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    int _row;
    int column;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  //Can also be done in xml by android:orientation="vertical"
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        params.weight = 1.0f;
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        //layout.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        _row=3;
        column=4;
        update();

    }


    public void update(){
        for (int i = 0; i < _row; i++) {
            LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(params);

            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                Button btnTag = new Button(this);
                btnTag.setLayoutParams(params);
                btnTag.setText("Button " + (j + 1 + (i * column)));
                btnTag.setId(j + 1 + (i * column));
                if ((i+j) % 2 == 0) {
                    btnTag.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);
                } else {
                    btnTag.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
                }

                row.addView(btnTag);
            }
            linearLayout.addView(row);
        }

        setContentView(linearLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, "Item name");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, Menu.NONE, "Item name");
        return true;
    }

    public void deleteSomething(){

        ((LinearLayout) linearLayout.getChildAt(1)).removeViewAt(0);
        ((LinearLayout) linearLayout.getChildAt(1)).removeViewAt(1);
        ((LinearLayout) linearLayout.getChildAt(1)).removeViewAt(2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case MENU_ITEM_ITEM1:
                deleteSomething();
                //linearLayout.removeAllViews();
                //_row=4;
                //column=5;
                //update();
                return true;
            case 2:
                deleteSomething();
                //linearLayout.removeAllViews();
                _row=6;
                column=3;
                update();
            default:
                return false;
        }


    }
}
```

There is something strange about this particular part:

```
public void deleteSomething(){

            ((LinearLayout) linearLayout.getChildAt(1)).removeViewAt(0);
            ((LinearLayout) linearLayout.getChildAt(1)).removeViewAt(1);
            ((LinearLayout) linearLayout.getChildAt(1)).removeViewAt(2);
        }
```

Comment out the first two line, the third button in the second rows get deleted without a problem; comment out the second one, the first two buttons in the second get deleted without a problem either. However, when you include all of the three lines, the app crashes immediately after you click the first item in the drop down menu.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to acknowledge dharms' explanation. Without his/her response, I wouldn't be able to come up with this solution. While his/her explanation is helpful, his/her proposed solution is incorrect. I'll post a correct solution in the following:
Change this

```
public void deleteSomething(){

    ((LinearLayout) linearLayout.getChildAt(1)).removeViewAt(0);
    ((LinearLayout) linearLayout.getChildAt(1)).removeViewAt(1);
    ((LinearLayout) linearLayout.getChildAt(1)).removeViewAt(2);
}
```

to:

```
public void deleteSomething(){
    for (int i = _row-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = column - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            ((LinearLayout) linearLayout.getChildAt(i)).removeViewAt(j);
        }
    }
}
```

The basic idea is that we don't want to change ids when deleting, and therefore we have to refer to their ids backwards.

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**

Your issue is you are referencing views by index. Each time you remove a view, the number of children decreases. Let's take a look at your example:

LinearLayout starts with 3 children:
[A, B, C]

First call
`((LinearLayout) linearLayout.getChildAt(1)).removeViewAt(0);`

Now your LinearLayout has 2 children:
[B, C]

Execute the next call
`((LinearLayout) linearLayout.getChildAt(1)).removeViewAt(1);`

Now your LinearLayout has 1 child:
[B]

Execute next call
`(LinearLayout) linearLayout.getChildAt(1)).removeViewAt(2);`

This throws an exception because index 2 is outside the range of your children (now size 1).

**The Solution**

Grab references to any views you want to remove first. Then remove them all from the LayoutGroup using `removeView(View view)`. Below is a simple example of how you might do that for demonstration purposes:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) linearLayout.getChildAt(1);
View a = layout.getChildAt(0);
View b = layout.getChildAt(1);
View c = layout.getChildAt(2);
layout.removeView(a);
layout.removeView(b);
layout.removeView(c);
```

Comment: I'm not trying to delete rows. I'm acutally trying to delete buttons within the rows.

Comment: I think the best way is to refer to their ids backwards

Comment: This is just a simple example. If you are always deleting a set of children views in sequence there is an additional method `removeViews(int start, int count)` that would be a better choice. My example covers if you are looking to remove views that may not be in a specific order.